# Time-Driven Trigger Not Working/Not Creating in Google Scripts onEdit

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to programmatically create time-driven triggers in Google Script using this code:

```
function RecurringTaskBuilder(spreadsheet, sheet, range, string) {
  var text = string.toLowerCase();
  Logger.log(text);

  if (/other/.test(text)) {
    var other = 1
  } else {
    var other = "" 
  }

  if (/monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday|sunday/.test(text)) {
    var days = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"];
    for (var index in days) {
      if (text.indexOf(days[index]) > -1) {
        var trigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger('RecurTask')
          .timeBased()
          .onWeekDay(eval("ScriptApp.WeekDay." + days[index].toUpperCase()))
          .create();
        var id = trigger.getUniqueId();
      }
    }
  } else if (/\d{1,2}\w{2}\s/.test(text)) {
      var trigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger('RecurTask')
        .timeBased()
        .onMonthDay(parseInt(text.match(/\d{1,2}/)))
        .create();
      var id = trigger.getUniqueId();
  } else if (text.indexOf(" day") > -1 && text.indexOf("days") == -1) { 
      Logger.log("starting day run");
      var trigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger('RecurTask')
        .timeBased()
        .everyDays(1)
        .create();
      var id = trigger.getUniqueId();
      Logger.log("ending day run");
  } else if (text.indexOf(" days") > -1 && /\d+/.test(text)) { 
      var trigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger('RecurTask')
        .timeBased()
        .everyDays(parseInt(text.match(/\d+/)))
        .create();
      var id = trigger.getUniqueId();
  } else {
      var id = "Failure";
  }

  Logger.log("finished if statement" + id);

  var target_sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Recurring Tasks");
  var row = range.getRow();
  var source_range = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 5);
  var lastrow = target_sheet.getLastRow();
  var target_range = target_sheet.getRange(lastrow + 1, 3, 1, 5);
  source_range.copyTo(target_range);

  var values = [[id, other]];
  target_sheet.getRange(target_range.getRow(), 1, 1, 2).setValues(values);
  Logger.log("ending run");
}
```

This code works properly and the trigger is created if I call it from the Google Script debugger using something like this:

```
function Test() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Incomplete Tasks");
  var range = sheet.getRange("H14");
  var string = range.getValue();
  RecurringTaskBuilder(spreadsheet, sheet, range, string)
}
```

But it doesn't trigger when I'm calling it from an onEdit (typing in "every other day" into a cell on my spreadsheet) with the exact same parameters.

On investigating, it seems to just get hung-up on the actual trigger creation and stop there, not giving any error message.

Please help, thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your [execution transcript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#execution_transcript) say? Also, is the onEdit a simple trigger or an installed trigger?

Comment: @JackBrown good call, I didn't know that was a feature. Here's the error I get:

[18-02-27 20:19:20:444 PST] Execution failed: You do not have permission to call newTrigger (line 36, file "OnEdit") [0.397 seconds total runtime]

Any idea why I don't have permission to create the trigger from my spreadsheet but I do within Google Script?

Comment: I am assuming you are using a function named `onEdit()` which runs when something is modified in the google sheets. These are simple triggers and have [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions) on what they can do. I would modify it to an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#g_suite_application_triggers) to see that works